# Can a symbol be an alias?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, symbols

In math, for example, proofs are often accompanied by 'QED' (*quod erat demonstrandum*) at the end, indicating their conclusion. Some authors use a square symbol (□) instead of QED, with the same meaning. Can we say □ is an alias for QED? If not, what would be the best word?

Comment: The best word is “symbol”.

Comment: If you look in [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/alias), you will see that only people and computer files/programs can have aliases. (I perceive the computing definition as somewhat technical, and not extendable to general non-animate things.)

Comment: @PeterShor - if you look at [the same dictionary on *aliasing*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/aliasing), you can see that the quotations (largely about images and signal processing) do not fit the definition and are better explained by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).  To me this suggests that *alias* may also have a wider meaning

Comment: @Henry: I know what *aliasing* (the gerund, not the noun *alias*) in signal processing is. It's something completely different, and is not applicable to the OP's question.

Comment: "□ is the symbol for QED" is what you want.

Comment: @Henry There are 3 senses of alias (1) an alternative name, usually for a person, (2) a computing construct where a file, command, etc, is given a different name, (3) in computer graphics and signal processing an artefact called by [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). None of these is relevant.

Comment: @StuartF The point of my comment was that the Cambridge Dictionary was incomplete (it only has two definitions) and illustrated this from its own quotations.  You have three, but again you cannot be sure there is no other usage, for example from its original Latin meaning of *another time or place* as in https://thelawdictionary.org/alias-writ/  You are correct that this is not relevant to □ or QED, but that was not my point

Comment: @Henry: and in fact, if you look in the OED, you will find that *alias* has indeed been used as another word for things, just like the OP wants to do. This usage is quite rare, as can be seen from the fact that it is not mentioned in the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/alias) or the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alias) dictionaries. It is thus not a very good idea to use the word *alias* for the symbol □.